# Panels block appending argument in url

Tags: 7, panels, views

I have a block which has the contextual filter to taxonomy id. 
I created a panel page which includes that block and I passed an argument some term (eg. 1234). Now in view more of that block it is displaying url as http://mysite.com/myviews/1234. I was expecting only http://mysite.com/myviews. I have 'Send Arguments' option unchecked. Not sure it it is possible to get rid of argument. Please suggest how to hide argument if possible.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Now in view more of that block"?

Comment: 'More link' of blocks is enabled and linked to some page.

Comment: I see, I assume you have tried setting the "Link display" on that to a custom URL?

Comment: Yes. It is linked to one of the view page from 'Link Display'. :-)

Comment: Have you tried "Custom URL" and put "myviews" there in the text field? Does it still attach the term id?

Comment: Yes that fixed the problem but I have linked block title to same url from panels setting and it didn't fix there. :-(